# How to assign an array to each of the nodes on omnet++ and store messages(values) in them?

Tags: network-programming, omnet++

Lets say, I have a network of 6 nodes from node1 to node6. Node1 generates a message every second and sends it to 5 other nodes in an order. The receiving node holds it for a few milliseconds and sends it back to node1 and the message gets destroyed.

I want to modify this process and instead build a  network where the message is a number. A random number is generated by Node1 and it is sent to each of the nodes in an order. Each of the five nodes will have an array of size N, and they should be able to store the number in their array up to a limit.

Lets consider the following scenario:

- Node1 sends a message to Node2 every 2 seconds
- Node2 takes 3 seconds to process the message
- If Node1 sends messages for 20 seconds, it'll have sent a total of 10 messages to Node2
- But Node1 takes 3 seconds to process a message. It needs a total of 30 seconds to process the messages received from Node1. That is why, when a message is received by Node2 from Node1, and if Node2 is occupied with processing a previous message, Node2 stores it in its array and pops the message as soon as its free.
- This process continues until all the messages are processed by Node2.

For example, a message(number) is sent from node1 to node5. Node5 stores that number in its array and pops the last insert and processes it and so on. Once the array is filled to its limit, node5 sends the message(number) to another node nearby.

How do I achieve this? I have done the tic-tac example, and currently have a working network with multiple nodes. I couldn't find anything related to having an array in each of the nodes. Is there an article or example I could look into?

For the current implementation, this is what the C++ file looks like: (txc1.cc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "txc1_m.h"

using namespace omnetpp;

class Node : public cSimpleModule
{
  private:
    // Set the pointers to nullptr, so that the destructor won't crash
    // even if initialize() doesn't get called because of a runtime
    // error or user cancellation during the startup process.
    cMessage *event = nullptr;  // pointer to the event object which we'll use for timing
    cMessage *nodeMsg = nullptr;  // variable to remember the message until we send it back
    int counter;
    int taskId;
    int taskSize;
    int seed = 0;
    bool firstMessageSent = false;

  protected:
    virtual Txc1Msg *generateMessage();
    virtual void forwardMessage(Txc1Msg *msg);
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(Node);
void Node::initialize()
{
    // Module 0 sends the first message
    event = new cMessage("event");
    if (getIndex() == 0) {
        scheduleAt(0.0, event);
    }
}
void Node::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    //All messages are generated from node0

    if (msg == event and getIndex() == 0) {
        Txc1Msg *msg = generateMessage();
        simtime_t delay = par("delayTime");
        scheduleAt(simTime()+1.0, event);
        forwardMessage(msg);
    }
    else {
        Txc1Msg *ttmsg = check_and_cast<Txc1Msg *>(msg);
        EV << "Is the message sent once? -> " << firstMessageSent << " \n ";
        if (firstMessageSent == true){
            bubble("ARRIVED, starting new one!");
            delete ttmsg;
            firstMessageSent = false;
        }
        else {
            // We need to forward the message.
            forwardMessage(ttmsg);
        }
    }
}

Txc1Msg *Node::generateMessage()
{
    // Produce source and destination addresses.
    int src = getIndex();  // our module index
    int n = getVectorSize();  // module vector size
    int dest = intuniform(0, n-2);
    if (dest >= src)
        dest++;
    char msgname[20];
    sprintf(msgname, "tic-%d-to-%d", src, dest);
    // Create message object and set source and destination field.
    Txc1Msg *msg = new Txc1Msg(msgname);
    msg->setSource(src);
    msg->setDestination(dest);
    return msg;
}

void Node::forwardMessage(Txc1Msg *msg)
{
    // Increment hop count.
    msg->setHopCount(msg->getHopCount()+1);
    seed += 1;
    // Same routing as before: random gate.
    int n = gateSize("gate");
    int k = seed %  n;
    EV << "This is n : " << n << " and this is k : " << k << " and this is seed : " << seed << "\n";
    firstMessageSent = true;
    EV << "Forwarding message " << msg << " on gate[" << k << "]\n";
    send(msg, "gate$o", k);
}
```

This is what the current ned file looks like : (name: nodes.ned)

```
package sampleplay;

simple Node {
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
        double cpuClock = 500;
        double memsize = 512;
        int numCores = 1;
        int processing_time @unit(s);
        int delayTime = default(2);
        
        gates:
        inout gate[];
}

network SampleConnection {
    types:
        channel Channel extends ned.DelayChannel {
            delay = 100ms;
        }
    
    submodules:
        node[8]: Node;
    connections: 
        node[0].gate++ <--> Channel <--> node[1].gate++;
        node[1].gate++ <--> Channel <--> node[2].gate++;
        node[1].gate++ <--> Channel <--> node[3].gate++;
        node[1].gate++ <--> Channel <--> node[4].gate++;
        node[1].gate++ <--> Channel <--> node[5].gate++;
        node[1].gate++ <--> Channel <--> node[6].gate++;
        node[1].gate++ <--> Channel <--> node[7].gate++;
```

This is what the msg file looks like: (filename: txc1.msg)

```
message Txc1Msg
{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int hopCount = 0;
}
```

This is what the .ini file looks like: (name: omnetpp.ini)

```
[General]
network = SampleConnection
**.limit = 17
**.delayTime = 1
**.taskGenerator.interarrival_time = 3s
```

To re-iterate, this is what the current implementation does:

- Messages are generated in an interval as mentioned in the code  `scheduleAt(simTime()+0.09, event);` node0 generates a message every time interval and sends it to node1
- node1 sends the message to other nodes, and decides which node to send to using the mod operation `int k = seed %  n;`
- Message gets destroyed as soon as it arrives back to node1 after visiting the node it was sent to

This is what I want the code to be able to do:

- The message should be a random number
- When messages are generated more frequently, the nodes should have an array to store them and should be able to process them in order
- When the array of nodeA is filled, it should be able to send it back to node1

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76316198/edit) the question and add the code that receives/sends messages?

Comment: What does it mean "The message should be a random number"? Does the message should contain an integer field?

Comment: yeah, the message should have a number such that it can be added to the array of the node it travels to. @JerzyD.

Comment: 1. How to understand "When messages are generated more frequently"? 2. Does "to store them" mean that you intend to store all received messages (not only numbers)? 3. What does mean "When the array of nodeA is filled"? Do you assume that the array has a limit?

Comment: 1. When messages are generated at the rate of 1message per second vs 10messages per second. When 10 messages are generated every second, and if a node takes 1second to process a message, we need to store the remaining 9messages in an array to process them in the future. As soon as the node is done processing the first message, it sends it to node1 and pops the first element from its array and starts processing it and so on.
2. We intend to store only numbers.
3. Yes, we assume that the array of the node has limits.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. Do you need an array for storing messages waiting for processing or an array for storing numbers from received messages or both? Could you edit your question and precisely describe your intention? It would be nice if you introduce some names of the array(s), random numbers etc.

Comment: @JerzyD. I added the working procedure of an array in the nodes. Please, let me know if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The process of generating and receiving the message with a random number may look like below.

1. Add an integer field in the message, for example:

   ```
   message Txc1Msg {
     int source;
     int destination;
     int hopCount = 0;
     int myNumber; // a new field
   }
   ```
2. Set a random number

   ```
   Txc1Msg *Node::generateMessage() {
     // ...
     Txc1Msg *msg = new Txc1Msg(msgname);
     msg->setSource(src);
     msg->setDestination(dest);
     msg->setMyNumber(intrand(100));  // set random number from 0..99
     return msg;
   }
   ```
3. To store received numbers one may use any C++ container, for example `std::vector`:

   ```
   class Node : public cSimpleModule {
     private:
     // ...
     std::vector<int> recVector;

   }
   ```
4. After receiving a message myNumber is added to recVector, for example:

   ```
   void Node::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
     if (msg == event and getIndex() == 0) {
       // ...
     } else {
       // ...
     } else {
        // We need to forward the message.
        int x = ttmsg->getMyNumber();
        recVector.push_back(x);   // store received number
        forwardMessage(ttmsg);
    }
   }
   ```